# Concatenate two fields

Tags: crystal-reports

I have these two fields in a dataset. How can I concatenate these in Crystal Reports to display next to each other?

```
select 
  CAST(T.GLTR_PSTNG_TYPE AS VARCHAR) REF_NO, 
  CAST(T.GLTR_DOC_CODE AS VARCHAR) GLTR_OUR_DOC_NO    
from dom
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will need to create a FORMULA to concatenate these strings.

In the *Field Explorer* , right click the *Formula Fields* and select *New*.

It will prompt you for a *Formula Name*. Enter the name of your choice, and hit enter.

In the *Formula Workshop* screen select the 2 fields you require to concat from the *Datasource*, drag them down to the edit section. The formula should look something like this

```
{YourDataSource.Field1} & " " & {YourDataSource.Field2}
```

Click *Save and Close*.

Now you can drag the Formula Field onto the report to view.