# Crystal Reports: Error in formula

Tags: crystal-reports

```
 {GLAS_GL_TRANSACTIONS.GLTR_PSTNG_TYPE} + {GLAS_GL_TRANSACTIONS.GLTR_PSTNG_NO}
```

I JUST invoke these two fields  from database and concatenate(+) by usin string(concatenate)

when i save this i got error like

string is required.......
what should i do? provide info......

Comment: Are both the fields (PSTNG_TYPE and PSTNG_NO) of type varchar (string)?

Comment: You'd do well in reading the answers to your questions a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned to you in [Concatenate Crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968155/concatenate-crystal/1968192#1968192)

you should use

```
{YourDataSource.Field1} & " " & {YourDataSource.Field2}
```

Make use of **&**, not **+**